# T-SQL - changing datetime to date data type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column `BirthDate` in a table that is using the `datetime` data type. Currently, the values resemble the format `1987-12-30 00:00:00.000`.

I would like to update all the rows of this table, changing them to the following format with the `date` data type: `1987-12-30`

I can run a SELECT...

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, BirthDate) FROM CUSTOMERLIST
```

But this is only affecting the display. I would like for it to update the entire column and also change the data type of that attribute as well. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will need to [`ALTER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) the table:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERLIST ALTER COLUMN BirthDate date not null
```

See [Sql Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/366a8/1)